# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty

I'm trying to setup a jetty-jersey rest on Java using IntelliJ IDE. My code works all fine inside IntelliJ but getting the following error post running .jar of maven build. Any suggestions on this issue will be very helpful. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

My code looks something like this.

```
ServletContextHandler context = new 
ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");

Server server = new Server(2222);
server.setHandler(context);
ServletHolder servlet = context.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
servlet.setInitOrder(0);

servlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", Resource.class.getCanonicalName());

try {
    server.start();
    server.join();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} finally {
    server.destroy();
}
```

My `pom.xml` looks like this

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.18.v20190429</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.18.v20190429</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
  <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm using cmd `mvn package` to create the jar files.

Comment: Your jars need to be on your classpath at runtime. This includes those dragged in by maven.